# PrimeNG pTemplate does render with Dialog on Angular unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, primeng

I'm doing a unit test on the component below.

```
<p-dialog
  [(visible)]="showModal"
  [modal]="true"
  [style]="{width: '35vw', height: '70vh'}"
  [baseZIndex]="10000"
  [draggable]="false"
  [resizable]="false"
  [closable]="false"
>
  <div class="dialog-content">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
    <div class="dialog-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onClose()">
        Cancel
      </button>
      <button
        *ngIf="showBtn"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary accept"
        [disabled]="appElement.disable"
        (click)="onAccept()"
      >
        Accept
      </button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dialog>
```

Unit test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [DialogModule],
      declarations: [FooComponent, CustomDirective]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable();
});

it('should accept button disabled', () => {
    component.showBtn = true;
    const acceptBtn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.accept');

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(acceptBtn.disabled).toBe(true);
});
```

The above unit test gives me an error where it does not query the element for the accept button. When I did a console, the below HTML template shown.

```
<div id="root3" ng-version="13.1.2">
   <p-dialog class="p-element" ng-reflect-visible="false" ng-reflect-modal="true" ng-reflect-base-z-index="10000" ng-reflect-draggable="false" ng-reflect-resizable="false" ng-reflect-closable="false">
      <!--bindings={}-->
   </p-dialog>
</div>
```

It looks like the ng-template part is not being rendered, which is why the test does not work. I tried adding PTemplate directive by declaring it in the `configureTestingModule` but it does not seem to work.

Any way to render the ptemplate when running the test?

Comment: isn't it just a typo. The p-dialog visible looks like it looks at `showModal`, but in your test you only set `show`. Also the output of the template say ng-visible[false] so ng-content of that p-dialog would not be rendered.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen it is a different use, which is to show the button not the modal. I should have made it specific. I'll update it

Comment: ok but you still need to set showModel to true else it will not render <ng-content> within the p-dialog

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen you're right. I can see now the rendered part of the footer.

Comment: the hint was in `ng-reflect-visible="false"` :)